# Check if username already exist - Prepared Statement

Tags: php, validation, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to check if username already exits in DB. have already done this easily with mysqli, but am trying to secure all my database query by using Prepared Statement.

Below is the code for both Mysqli and prepared statement.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// start session
session_start();

// include connection
require_once('include/connection.php');

// if user is loggin, redirected to homepage
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$error[] = "";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname = trim($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = trim($_POST['lastname']);
    $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
    $user_name = trim($_POST['user_name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    //     $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    //     $confirm_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($_POST['confirm_password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));


    // password hash security
    $hash_pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 

    extract($_POST);

    // validate form field
    if (empty($firstname)){     
        $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your first name';        
    }else{
        if (strlen($firstname) < 3){ 
            $error[] = 'First Name is too short';
        }
    }
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
        $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }

    if (empty($lastname)){     
        $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your last name';        
    }else{
        if (strlen($lastname) < 3){ 
            $error[] = 'Last Name is too short';
        }
    }
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
        $error[] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    if (empty($user_name)){     
        $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your username';        
    }else{
        if (strlen($user_name) < 3){ 
            $error[] = 'UserName is too short';
        }
    }

    //if( $query = "select * from user where user_name = "."'".trim($user_name)."'" );

    //    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    //    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    //        $error[] = "User Name Already Exist, try other";
    //        header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    //    }

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = ?"));
        //  $stmt = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        /* bind param variables */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $user_name);
        /* execute statement */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        /* store result */
        // mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        /* num rows */
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {

            $error[] = "User Name Already Exist, try other";
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
    //}   


        // validate user type option
        if (empty($user_type)){     
            $error[] = 'Please select user type from list';        
        }


        // set email filter validation 
        if (empty($email)){     
            $error[] = 'Field empty, please enter your email address';        
        }else {
            $query = "select * from user where email = "."'".trim($email)."'";

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                $error[] = "Chosen email Already Exist, please choose another ";
                //  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }

            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $error[] = "Invalid email format"; 
            }                               
        }


        if (empty($password)){     
            $error[] = 'Field empty, please create a password';        
        }else{
            if (strlen($password) < 6){ 
                $error[] = 'Password is too short';
            }
            if (strlen($password) > 15){ 
                $error[] = 'Password is too long';                  
            }                          

            if ( !preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $password) ) {
                $error[] = "Password must include at least one CAPS! ";
            }else{

                if( !preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password) ) {
                    $error[] = "Password must include at least one NUMBER! ";
                }  
            }
        }

        // set field validation for confirm password
        if (empty($confirm_password)){     
            $error[] = 'Field empty, please confirm your password';        
        }else{
            if ($password != $confirm_password) {
                $error[] = 'Error... Passwords do not match';
            }
        } 

        //if no errors have been created carry on
        if(!isset($error)){

            $created_at = date('Y-m-d');
            $queryInsert = "insert into user 
                                (firstname,lastname,user_name,
                                 user_type,email,password,
                                 created_at) 
                            values ('$firstname','$lastname','$user_name',
                                    '$user_type','$email','$hash_pass',
                                    '$created_at')";
            $resInsert = mysqli_query($con,$queryInsert);
            if($resInsert){

                $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Successfully registered, login here!";
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit;

            }else{
                $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Some error, try again";
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }
        }
    //}
    }

    // exit mysqli connection


    // title page
    $title = "Registration Page";

    // include header
    require_once('include/header.php');
    ?>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['main_notice'])) { 
    ?>      
        <div class="main-notice">
            <p>
    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['main_notice']; 
        //unset($_SESSION['main_notice']);
    ?>
            </p>
        </div>  
    <?php 
    }   
    ?>
        <div>
    <?php
        //check for any errors
        if(isset($error)){
            foreach($error as $error){
                echo '<p style="color: red">'.$error.'</p>';
            }
        }
    ?>
           <form name="register" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" method="post">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['firstname']; } ?>'</td>
              </tr>        
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['lastname']; } ?>'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="user_name" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['user_name']; } ?>'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Type</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="user_type" required>
                        <option selected>Please choose user type</option>
                        <option value="member">RSW</option>
                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="leader">SP</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="email" name="email" value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>'</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value='<?php if(isset($error)) ?>'></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Confirm Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value='<?php if(isset($error)) ?>'></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><a href="index.php">Login</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          </form>   
        </div>

    <?php
    if(is_file('include/footer.php'))
        include_once('include/footer.php');
    ?>
```

Have comment out the mysqli. Am not receiving error but the form is not executing.

**Note** have also comment out the mysqli_stmt_store_result because I don't see what that does really.

Comment: You need to remove the `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` line as that is done by the `mysqli_stmt_execute($result);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly,,, thanks for your input... have comment that out couple of time still not executing. instead of displaying error message... username already exit. page refresh and return field value

Comment: You have all sorts of other errors judging by the picture you showed me in a comment to my now deleted answer. Maybe you should post all the code and then we can solve all the problems in one go

Comment: Have re-posted all the code, hopefully this will help

Comment: Have provided with a solution. Refer to it and share thought if you face any hindrance in development.

Comment: Code Edited. Please have a check now.

Answer (score -2):

You have used prepared statement and why for you combine the `mysqli.*` along with all the queries that you execute. You can better change the queries as per the normal prepared statement process.

You can use the `num_rows` so that it will help you to fetch the count of the queries executed above.

> Replace your Prepared Statement like this:

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = ?");
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $user_name);// Here you will bind the parameters 
$stmt -> execute(); // here it will execute the statement
$numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows; // here if will fetch the count
if($numberofrows > 0) {
  $error[] = "User Name Already Exist, try other";
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
else
{
 // This part is for user name mot present.
}
?>
```

> The Mysqli way you can have like this.

```
<?php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."'");
$stmt->execute(); // here it will execute the statement
$numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows; // here if will fetch the count
if($numberofrows > 0) {
  $error[] = "User Name Already Exist, try other";
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
else
{
 // if the user name is not present
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks I will make the change with your suggestion and revert back to you. thanks for your input.

Comment: How is your code any different from what the OP have?

Comment: @OlamilekanOshodi. Have you obtained the output as required...

Comment: am just doing it right now.

Comment: Ya do and let me know since you have told you have been taking my suggestion long back. :)

Comment: Fine :) Work cool

Comment: @NareshKumar.P... have just check with your suggestion. after the up the username field with existing username name and submit the request the page went blank

Comment: It is having a redirection issue right that means... Other than that all correct ah @OlamilekanOshodi.

Comment: but this code still work `     if( $query = "select * from user where user_name = "."'".trim($user_name)."'" );

                          $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                          if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                              $error[] = "User Name Already Exist, try other";
                            // header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                          } `

Comment: Your if statement looks incorrect and you no need if statement over there. You can have else part over there .

Comment: @NareshKumar.P No mate he doesn't work. what i don't is, it work with mysqli query, but doesn't with prepare stateement

Comment: Oh that means you can have a look . Pls wait i will repost my code ..

Comment: Re posted it with both codes.

Comment: Check and let me know if you face any hindrance :)

Comment: K so basically I should comment out the param

Comment: will that leave a hole in sql injection.

Comment: Yes. But if you use parametric statement it will be escaping from SQL Injection..

Comment: @NareshKumar.P hello am getting this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in`

Comment: the where username = concatenating, do i need to remove some of them semicolon

Comment: Nope you no need to do anything. You can test it as such what i have given

Comment: have tested it like but i was getting above error syntax error

Comment: have also test with this code  ` if($stmt = "SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE user_name = ?");
// prepare the query, bind the variable and execute
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user_name);
$stmt->execute();
// grab the result
$stmt->store_result();
// get the count
$numRows = $stmt->num_rows();
if( $numRows )
{
     echo "<p class='red'>Email is already registered with us</p>";
}
else
{
    // ....
} `but am getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object `